# Database design - Split database table of orders into buy/sell

Tags: database-design

Ok. So I need to store some information about an in-game market that consists of buy and sell orders.

Each order (buy and sell) in the table consists of an itemID, orderID, price, available, remaining and date.

My first thought (thinking in a DRY context) was to use one table and add a entry for if it is a buy or sell order.

The number of items is around 100 so won't be so much of an issue. I am looking to do some analysis on the results.

Should I use 1 table or 2?

Comment: If the fields are the same, probably 1 table.

Comment: You should do as you suggest, one table and a buy/sell flag.